# Render EJS partial on client side - Could not find the include file error

Tags: node.js, ejs, client-side

I am trying to update with socket.io a data which is coming for some partials.
I have a partial called info_card.ejs in partials package and it has two params: title and info. I have tried rendering the following code:

```
   <% info_cards.forEach(function(card) { %>
         <%- include("../partials/info_card", card) %>
   <% }); %>
```

The first render is made by the server, and when I am trying to render in the client side (inside a js script) as following:

```
const update_info_cards =
            [
                {title: "title1", info: "info1"},
                {title: "title1", info: "info2"}
            ]
  
        var html = ejs.render(`<% info_cards.forEach(function(card) { %>
            <%- include("../partials/info_card", card) %>
            <% }); %>`, {info_card: update_info_cards })
```

I get this error:

```
    1| <% info_cards.forEach(function(card) { %>
 >> 2|             <%- include("../partials/info_card", card) %>
    3|             <% }); %>

Could not find the include file "../partials/info_card"
```

Don't know how to fix it, I have tried to change the path for such a long time, but still get this error. I have also tried to look up for some answers on the internet - couldn't find any.

- I saw that I can't do include on client side, so what's the alternative, because I really can't see me coping all the html code of the card multiple times?

Thanks!